# IIS 10 - JSON files are not serving even after configured MIME and Handlers

Tags: node.js, json, iis, static, mime

I have deployed a web application in IIS 10 (Windows 10) build from Node.

Files structure

[image: Files structure]
  
  
I am unable to access the JSON files (for eg., http://localhost:3000/manifest.json) using the direct URL.

Receiving the following error,
[image: Error]


I have set MIME Type as follows,

[image: MIME Type - JSON]
  

I have tried the Handler Mapping too,

[image: Handler Mapping for JSON]
  
  
My web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Assets" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="([\S]+[.](html|htm|svg|js|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg|json))" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <handlers>
      <add name="StaticFileModuleJson" path="*.json*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

I notice that your rewrite rule have rewritten .json to .js. It has nothing to do with the handler because static file hanlder is still handling the request.

[image]
[image]

Please swap the index of js and json.

```
 <rule name="Static Assets" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="([\S]+[.](html|htm|svg|json|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg|js))" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

[image]